# How to use custom scroll bar on dynatree plugin?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, dynatree

I have integrated the nice dynatree plugin on my web site.
It works fine, but now I want to change scrollbar style of dynatree in such a way to suit my web site's theme.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change `ui.dynatree.css` file or add your own rule. For example change code as below:

```
ul.dynatree-container
{
    /* ... */
    overflow: scroll;
    /* ... */
}
```